# How can I loop the hidden layers in the program written using python3?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have written code to perform the hidden layer method of deep learning.
Every hidden layer analyses the input data and passes it to other hidden layers until the analyzed data appears.

It is possible to make as many hidden layers as I want. But, that would take a very long time and effort if I want to make, say, 50 hidden layers. Therefore, I thought of using the loop function in order to save time and effort. Yet, it is difficult as I am new to programming.

here is the program:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)

n_nodes_hl1 = 500
n_nodes_hl2 = 500
n_nodes_hl3 = 500

n_classes = 10
batch_size = 100

# height * width

x = tf.placeholder('float',[None, 784])
y = tf.placeholder('float')

def neural_network_model(data):

   # (input_data * wehights) + biases

   hidden_1_layer = {'weight' :tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, n_nodes_hl1])),
                     'biases' :tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}

   hidden_2_layer = {'weight' :tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])),
                     'biases' :tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))}

   hidden_3_layer = {'weight' :tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_nodes_hl3])),
                     'biases' :tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3]))}

   output_layer = {'weight' :tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3, n_classes])),
                     'biases' :tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}

   #    # (input_data * wehights) + biases

   l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_1_layer['weight']), hidden_1_layer['biases'])
   l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

   l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1, hidden_2_layer['weight']), hidden_2_layer['biases'])
   l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

   l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2, hidden_3_layer['weight']), hidden_3_layer['biases'])
   l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

   output = tf.matmul(l3, output_layer['weight']) + output_layer['biases']

   return output

def train_neural_network(x):
   prediction = neural_network_model(x)
   cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction,y) )
   optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

   hm_epochs = 20

   with tf.Session() as sess:
      sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

      for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
      epoch_loss = 0
      for _ in range(int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)):
         epoch_x, epoch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
         _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict = {x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y})
         epoch_loss += c
      print('Epoch', epoch, 'completed out of', hm_epochs, 'loss:', epoch_loss)

      correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction,1), tf.argmax(y,1))
      accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
      print('accuracy:', accuracy.eval({x:mnist.test.images, y:mnist.test.labels}))

train_neural_network(x)
```

and here is the part that I need to loop:

```
def neural_network_model(data):

   # (input_data * wehights) + biases

   hidden_1_layer = {'weight' :tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, n_nodes_hl1])),
                     'biases' :tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}

   hidden_2_layer = {'weight' :tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])),
                     'biases' :tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))}

   hidden_3_layer = {'weight' :tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_nodes_hl3])),
                     'biases' :tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3]))}

   output_layer = {'weight' :tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3, n_classes])),
                     'biases' :tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}

   #    # (input_data * wehights) + biases

   l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_1_layer['weight']), hidden_1_layer['biases'])
   l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

   l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1, hidden_2_layer['weight']), hidden_2_layer['biases'])
   l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

   l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2, hidden_3_layer['weight']), hidden_3_layer['biases'])
   l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

   output = tf.matmul(l3, output_layer['weight']) + output_layer['biases']

   return output
```

Comment: and what is the problem? Just apply regular python loop

Comment: You might want to take a look at this tutorial for multilayer perceptron using theano: http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/mlp.html

Comment: @Thomas Pinetz This tutorial is helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want a method like below to create a single hidden layer:

```
def make_hidden(input_num, hidden_num):
  return {'weight' :tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([input_num, 
                                                  hidden_num])),
          'biases' :tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden_num]))}
```

The output layer can be created the same way as you did.

```
def make_output(hidden_num, output_classes):
  return {'weight' :tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden_num, 
                                                  n_classes])),
          'biases' :tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}
```

Then you have a list that stores the number of nodes at each layer, starting at input layer, ending at the last hidden layer:

```
n_nodes = [0, 784, 500, 500, 500]
     #     |___ dummy value so that n_nodes[i] and n_nodes[i+1] stores
     #          the input and hidden number of the i-th hidden layer
     #          (1-based) because layers[0] is the input.
```

Then your `neural_network_model` can be simplified:

```
def neural_network_model(data, n_nodes):
   layers = []*len(n_nodes)
   layers[0] = data
   for i in in range(1, n_nodes-1):
     hidden_i = make_hidden(n_nodes[i], n_nodes[i+1]
     layers[i] = tf.add(tf.matmul(layers[i-1], hidden_i['weight']), hidden_i['biases'])
     layers[i] = tf.nn.relu(layers[i])

   output_layer = make_output(n_nodes[-1], n_classes)
   output = tf.matmul(layers[-1], output_layer['weight']) + output_layer['biases']

   return output
```

You might still need minor changes to make the code work. I hope you get the point of the loop over hidden layers.